# Replace ":" with "|" php

Tags: php, pipe, preg-replace

I want to replace ":" with a "|" in this case:

```
$path="C:/example";
```

I want `$path` to be like `"C|/example"`

I am trying `preg_replace('/:/',"|", $path);`

Comment: use str_replace() php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php instead of preg_replace

Comment: Actually, your code works. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: @georg From the sample I'd bet it's one of those cases where OP simply didn't assign the return value back.

Answer (score 6):

```
$path = str_replace(':', '|', $path);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 3):

Use `str_replace`:

```
$value = str_replace(":", "|", $path);
```